# Header Authorization backslash

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to POST body to an REST API using fetch and Authorization with Bearer header in React Native App.

I don't understand why, but the the Authorization value on the headers add some backslash (so the header is wrong).

```
  if (!JSON.parse(logoutMode) || customToken) {
    params.headers = {
      ...params.headers,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token || customToken}`
    };
  }

  console.log(params.headers);
  console.log(params.headers.Authorization);
  console.log(`${token}`);
```

You can see the `console.log()` result :

```
[Sat Oct 17 2020 11:53:17.527]  LOG      {"Authorization": "Bearer {\"session\":\"v1:whut-xYXgZJRw-tSsKOE=\",\"scopes\":[\":*\"],\"signature\":\"-GLiIN9O0SfAzMofgIQh1GbiI9cMEvQVqJLD98atmBQ=\"}", "Content-Type": "application/json"}
[Sat Oct 17 2020 11:53:17.529]  LOG      Bearer {"session":"v1:whut-xYXgZJRw-tSsKOE=","scopes":[":*"],"signature":"-GLiIN9O0SfAzMofgIQh1GbiI9cMEvQVqJLD98atmBQ="}
[Sat Oct 17 2020 11:53:17.529]  LOG      {"session":"v1:whut-xYXgZJRw-tSsKOE=","scopes":[":*"],"signature":"-GLiIN9O0SfAzMofgIQh1GbiI9cMEvQVqJLD98atmBQ="}
```

The first log is the problem: I don't really understand why the first log add backslash :/

I've try to add `replace()` method, but without result.

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: `{"session":"v1:whut-xYXgZJRw-tSsKOE=","scopes":[":*"],"signature":"-GLiIN9O0SfAzMofgIQh1GbiI9cMEvQVqJLD98atmBQ="}`
This is a json response parse it first
Then get session /signature value as token

Comment: Hello :) Not sure to understand :/

Comment: It is a json object first parse it using `var obj = JSON.parse('{"session":"v1:whut-xYXgZJRw-tSsKOE=","scopes":[":*"],"signature":"-GLiIN9O0SfAzMofgIQh1GbiI9cMEvQVqJLD98atmBQ="} ');` this methd 

Then call `obj.session`

Answer (score 0):

**There is no problem**. The backslash is there (in the output) because the value is wrapped in double quotes, which requires escaping. The value is wrapped in double quotes (formatted like a string literal), because it is output as part of an object.

The value itself, and the header that is sent, are fine.